# Push notifications opt-in cases

Tags: android, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I've been searching for answers for a while and haven't found ones, so I'm asking here:
If a user plays a mobile app and opted in to receive push notifications, will he remain opted-in in the following cases:

1. Uninstalling and reinstallin the app.
2. Updating the game's version
3. Changing the device

I would like to understand these cases for both iOS and Android 13, but iOS is even more important for me, so I'd appreciate it if someone could assist here, thanks!

I tried to find answers in both Apple and Android documentation, without any success.